# What's that thing in Captain America Civil war promo images

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america-civil-war

In the top right corner of below image

[image: Image with flying object in corner]

There is a small plane like thing, this has also been seen in some more pictures, but this does not look something SHIELD might have used before, So my question is what is that thing, is this some kind of equipment used by FALCON or somebody else and why is it in the promo pictures, does it hold great importance?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It's a mechanical bird for the Falcon. In the comics, Falcon has [Redwing](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Redwing_(Earth-616)), a falcon Sam bought in Rio, and has been in the comics as far back as Captain America Vol 1 #186 (June, 1975), as old as Falcon himself.

[image]

[They even have a mental link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falcon_(comics)):

> As part of a plot against Captain America, the Red Skull uses the Cosmic Cube, a creation that allows its user to alter reality, to mentally fuse Wilson with Redwing, creating a "super-normal mental link" that would, with time and concentration, give Wilson broad powers over all birds.

Like all magical animal sidekicks, Redwing is also part of the Pet Avengers, along with Lockjaw, and Throg.

### In Captain America: Civil War, [Redwing is now a drone](http://www.ew.com/article/2015/08/15/marvel-d23-expo-civil-war). As screened to the D23 audience in August 2015:

> 11:21 a.m. Here’s what we see: The new Avengers are in buildings overlooking a crowded market in what appears to be a third-world country. “Eyes on target, folks,” Captain America says. Falcon says, “Red Wing, launch,” and a small drone hovers free and dives down to the street, swooping beneath a truck, which is loaded with explosives.

So it's importance is really fan wank material. Redwing is as old as Falcon, and just as important to the character as the shield or Bucky is for Cap. Adding Redwing is a nod to Sam Wilson's comic roots, and doesn't detract from the story.

<strike>It likely won't be too critical to the plot though. Like most of their powers, it will probably get one scene and then not seen again.</strike> Correction, Redwing was used in the big fight scenes, at the beginning and during the TeamCap vs TeamIronMan brawl, to great avail, and mentioned many times. Redwing has sensors, cameras, remote targeting, a grappling hook, missiles/bombs/guns.

If you notice, Redwing is in most of the promo pictures.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5):

**Update**

Some leaked footage now contains a scene with Redwing. Evidently it's launched from Falcon's backpack, has an incredibly tight turning circle and some sort of infra-red sensors that link to Falcon's new red goggles

---

According to the footage shown at the recent D23 exhibition, The Falcon's traditional sidekick [Redwing](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Redwing_(Earth-616)) (a large bird that Sam Wilson bought while on holiday) will be a powered drone.

Per [Comicbook Resources](http://comicbook.com/2015/08/10/captain-america-civil-war-trailer-released/)

> Another scene revealed the Falcon's pet falcon, Redwing.
>
> **But he's not the winged bird we've come to know and love - he is, in
>   fact a drone!**

The following artwork was apparently issued (briefly) via Marvel's official channel in Spain, then [removed shortly afterwards](http://www.comicbookresources.com/article/comic-reel-new-civil-war-promo-art-shows-off-opposing-sides-matt-and-karen-get-close-in-daredevil-pic). It appears to show the drone in more detail.

[image]